# Список локальных пользователей bat-файлом

Tags: windows, bat, список

Задача сделать средствами bat-файла список локальных пользователей
с параметрами вроде времени последнего входа и действие пароля.

Как можно ли объединить выполнение
    net user user1
    net user user2
    и т.п.

и отфильтровать вывод на определенные параметры.

Comment: ActiveDirectory в наличии?

Comment: Нет, локальные пользователи, вроде Администратора нужны

Comment: Тогда WMI без AD не поможет, либо надо спец. модуль ставить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Команда **net user** выводит имена пользователей таблицей: в 3 столбца шириной 25 символов. Получается, нужно собрать все строки таблицы в строковую переменную, а затем распарсить её.
Проще воспользоваться командой, которая сразу выведет имена локальных пользователей: **wmic useraccount where (localaccount="True") get Name**.
А для каждого полученного имени уже заставить в цикле выводить команду: **net user <имя>**